# Cur part of column's string value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
Type   Value
A      rwegbUBW EUOGBWPG wefuhuwef weg
B      wkefuhO EFHUWH efihiuheiwfhw weft f
C      weo8 hq3rh fqq qfee fqf
```

Its an example and real values in my dataframe are much much longer. So i want to cut them and  leave only 10 first words in each of them. How could i do that? In this example you can leave only 3 first words

Comment: Not a great example because (1) it is not directly reproducible (as dput() output is) and (2) none of the values have more than 10 words.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

```
df$Value <- sub("((\\w+ ){3}).*","\\1",df$Value)
```

If you want the first 10 words you'll need replace `{3}` with `{10}`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that takes in a string, splits it on the character " ", selects the first x-elements (2 in this example because your data never has 10) and then returns the concatenated string. You can then apply this function to your data column:

```
df <- data.frame(Type = c("A", "B", "C"),
                 Value = c("rwegbUBW EUOGBWPG wefuhuwef weg", 
                           "wkefuhO EFHUWH efihiuheiwfhw weft f",
                           "weo8 hq3rh fqq qfee fqf"),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

select_2 <- function(text) {
  words <-  unlist(strsplit(text, " "))[1:2]
  paste(words, collapse = ' ')
}

df$Value2 <- sapply(df$Value, select_2)
```